# How to call parameterized Jsonnet from bash?

Tags: jsonnet

I can't understand how to best to parameterize a Jsonnet file so that I may call the same file from bash and from another Jsonnet file.

Assuming I have a simple template called template.jsonnet:

```
{
  // Required arguments
  name:: error "'name' must be specified",
  port:: error "'port' must be specified",

  ...,
}
```

I can readily incorporate this into another Jsonnet file and provide its required parameter values with:

```
{
  local template = = import "./template.jsonnet";

  template + {
    name:: "service",
    port:: 8080,
}
```

I'm struggling to determine the intended way that I could call `template.jsonnet` from bash to achieve the same result.

I can use `--ext-str` but this appears to require `std.extVar(x)`

A GitHub [issue](https://github.com/google/jsonnet/issues/147) suggests that `--tla-code` may be an alternative to std.extVar() but I don't understand how to use it for my needs.

A follow-up question is: how do do this for a parameter this is an array:

```
{
  local template = = import "./template.jsonnet";

  template + {
    name:: "service",
    port:: [8080,8081,8082],
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The most direct way is to use some inline jsonnet:

```
jsonnet -e '(import "template.jsonnet") + { name: "service", port: 8080 }'
```

For easier parametrization, you can use extVars or top-level-arguments (TLAs).

```
jsonnet -e 'function(name, port) (import "template.jsonnet") + { name: name, port: port }' --tla-str name="blah" --tla-code port='[8080, 8081]'
```

or

```
jsonnet -e '(import "template.jsonnet") + { name: std.extVar("name"), port: std.extVar("port") }' --ext-str name="blah" --ext-code port='[8080, 8081]'
```

A better way is to make template.jsonnet a function and use `--tla-code`/ `--tla-str`:

```
  function(name, port) {
    name:: name,
    port:: port
    // Sidenote: the fields are hidden here, because they use ::,
    // use : to make them appear when the object is manifested.
    // Sidenote 2: You can provide default argument values. 
    // For example function(name, port=8080) makes port optional.
  }
```

Then in another jsonnet file you can use it as follows:

```
local template = import "./template.jsonnet";
{

  filled_template: template(
    name="service",
    port=8080 // or port=[8080,8081,8082]
  )
}
```

And you can use the template from shell as follows:

```
jsonnet --tla-code name='"some name"' --tla-code port=8080 template.jsonnet
```

Note how quotation marks are necessary for name (without outer `'` they would be interpreted by shell). That's because you can pass any jsonnet code that evaluates to any type in `tla-code`.

If you want to pass a string verbatim you can use `--tla-str`:

```
jsonnet --tla-str name="some name" --tla-code port=8080 template.jsonnet
```

On the other hand you can pass an array (or an object, or any jsonnet code) to `--tla-code`:

```
jsonnet --tla-code name='"some name"' --tla-code port='[8080, 8081, 8082]' template.jsonnet
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to change your `template.jsonnet` you can use a wrapper file to provide the interface that I described:

template_func.jsonnet:

```
local template = import "./template.jsonnet";
function(name, port) template + {
  name: name,
  port: port
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this exhaustive and clearly explained answer. This helps me immensely not only address my question but to use Jsonnet more effectively. Thank you.